# Android Canvas: make a drawn line fade/alphaAnimation away on touch

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have a `Canvas` on which I am drawing lines bewteen points in a `onTouchEvent()`. When the user makes an invalid selection on where to place the line, I draw a red line instead of a black one. However I want the red line to fade away over the next 500-1000ms.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do it, and if it is even possible to animate a single line inside a `Canvas`.

I have split the dots, the valid black lines and the invalid red line(s) between 3 different bitmaps inside my:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Fade Red Line
    canvas.drawBitmap(fBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    // Lines
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    // Dots
    canvas.drawBitmap(iBitmap, 0, 0, null); 
}
```

and inside my onTouch function are my `drawLines()`.

I was wondering if I can use an AlphaAnimation for this, or if I have to use a timer system to loop over the `fBitmap` with the red line I want to fade out over time.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT:** Okay here's how I eventually solved it after coming back to it a year later:

I implemented a SurfaceView and created a thread to continuously update the Canvas.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            continue;
        }

        decreaseLineOpacity();
        drawLinesInvalid();

        /* Other things to draw*/

        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

        canvas.drawBitmap(fBitmap, centerPointWidth, centerPointHeight, null);
        // mBitmap is the middleground with the line that fades away.
        // and is bound to mCanvas for drawing
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, centerPointWidth, centerPointHeight, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(iBitmap, centerPointWidth, centerPointHeight, null);

        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

And then the methods that take care of changing the opacity and drawing the line, I store each line I draw in a Queue, until it reaches an opacity of 0, and then I remove it so only the lines that need to be animated are left:

```
    private void drawLinesInvalid() {
        Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator();
        // Loop through each element in the Queue, delete it from the bitmap with the porter
        // duff mode to keep the transparancy of the layer. Then draw line with the given opacity
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int[] invalidLine = iterator.next();
            float[] line = {invalidLine[1], invalidLine[2], invalidLine[3], invalidLine[4]};
            Xfermode originalXfermode = paint.getXfermode();
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            mCanvas.drawLines(line, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(originalXfermode);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setAlpha(invalidLine[0]);

            mCanvas.drawLines(line, paint);

        }
    }

// Call this function in the onTouch method
    private void addLineToInvalidList(float[] line) {
        // Store each line a queue with its current opacity
        int[] lineWithOpacity = new int[5];
        lineWithOpacity[0] = 250;
        lineWithOpacity[1] = (int) line[0];
        lineWithOpacity[2] = (int) line[1];
        lineWithOpacity[3] = (int) line[2];
        lineWithOpacity[4] = (int) line[3];
        invalidLines.add(lineWithOpacity);
    }

    private void decreaseLineOpacity() {
        Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator();
        // Remove all lines that are finished animating (opacity = 0)
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int[] line = iterator.next();
            if (line[0] == 0) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        // Decrease opacity on lines that are left
        iterator = invalidLines.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int[] line = iterator.next();
            line[0] -= 10;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are drawing all three bitmaps on the same view, using an `AlphaAnimation` may be a bit tricky.

I would suggest spawning a thread that changes the alpha value of the invalid red line(s) bitmap over time (sleeping for set intervals with `Thread.sleep`). However, for this to perform well you should look into using a `SurfaceView` as calling `postInvalidate` multiple times may be quite costly (unless this is running on Android 3.0+ with hardware acceleration).

Comment: Okay, so am I layering a surface view with only red line(s) in it above my current view, or am I placing everything inside a SurfaceView?

Comment: To keep things simple, place everything in the `SurfaceView`. There are many tutorials on this and it will open up doors to many other visual extensions. If you wish to separate the red lines into a separate `View`, then you should consider just using the `AlphaAnimation`.

Comment: Finally came back to this app, added my solution using the thread and surface view you suggested, thanks.